# How to add gesture recognizer with class method as selector?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add a gesture recognizer on my UIImageView from my UIViewController extensions methods.

The method I want to fire when the image is tapped is a class method declared in my swift extensions :

```
class func openPopViewWithText(text: String!) {
    print("fire!")
}
```

I add the selector from my extensions class too. This is how I add the selector :

```
infoImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.openPopViewWithText(_:)) ))
```

And this is the error that I get when I tap the ImageView :

```
[XXXDisplayStatsViewController openPopViewWithText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd31520ada0
```

Complete code in my extensions class :

```
public extension UIViewController {


func addInfoImageViewWithText(infoText: String){
    let margins : CGFloat = 30.0
    let infoImageView : UIImageView =  UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "info"));
    let yOrigin : CGFloat = ((self.view.y + self.view.height) - infoImageView.height) - margins
    infoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(margins, yOrigin, infoImageView.width + 5, infoImageView.height + 5)
    self.view.insertSubview(infoImageView, atIndex: 0)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(infoImageView)
    infoImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    infoImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.openPopViewWithText(_:)) ))
}

class func openPopViewWithText(text: String!) {
    print("fire!")
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that first argument in your `openPopViewWithText` function is `String` rather than a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. When you tap on the `UIImageView` gesture recognizer is fired and it passes the gesture recognizer instance to the selector so you can track its properties. So what you should do is change the current function signature to this:

```
class func openPopViewWithText(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("fire!")
}
```

Other than that, you should not use class functions because you're not be able to access any `UIViewController` properties.

Comment: I understood for the first problem. For the 2nd problem I don't want to access any of my UIViewController properties. I just want to create a generic method for all of my UIViewControllers which display a popViewController when image is tapped

Comment: So you're good to go then, just swap the `String` type to `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: `... 
infoImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        infoImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.openPopViewWithText(_:)) ))
    }
    
    class func openPopViewWithText(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("fire!")
    }`

It doesn't solve the problem I always have the error,but I think it comes from the target that I set in addGestureRecognizer method, I have set `self`, so the viewController attempts to find this method  `openPopViewControllerWithText`but as this method is a class method, it can't find it

Comment: Okay I just removed the `class` keyword so now my view controller know the method it works, the problem was coming from the recognizer parameter as you said. Resolved, thank you guy